# No declaration can be found for element (XML Schema)

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, schema

I usually get this kind of error when not being on-line:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 55; columnNumber: 33; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring/hazelcast-spring-2.1.xsd', 
because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

...no declaration can be found for element 'hz:hazelcast'.
```

What is the solution so that it doesn't have to connect to the internet just for this everytime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say in your question exactly how you're loading the XML file that requires this schema, but by its name it would appear to be something to do with Spring bean configurations.  Spring has a mechanism for components that provide their own schemas to bundle these inside their JAR files so they don't have to be fetched from the internet.  This involves a `java.util.Properties` format file named `META-INF/spring.schemas` in the JAR file, which contains lines that map http URLs to local paths (within the JAR file), for example

```
http\://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring/hazelcast-spring-2.1.xsd=hazelcast-spring-2.1.xsd
```

(from `hazelcast-spring-2.1.3.jar`).

So I suspect what's happening here is that you're referring to a different schema version from the version of hazelcast you're actually using, which would mean the schema you request isn't listed in the `spring.schemas` catalog and it therefore has to go to the internet to download it.  If, for example, you have `hazelcast-spring-2.5.jar` then you need to use the matching `http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring/hazelcast-spring-2.5.xsd` in the `xsi:schemaLocation`.

Comment: I see, that could be the problem

Answer (score 1):

Download the xsd and keep it in your project. Access the xsd using the following code below

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(<your>.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnMarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();


SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
URL tmpurl = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("file.xsd");
Schema s = schemaFactory.newSchema(tmpurl);
jaxbUnMarshaller.setSchema(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy that XSD into WEB-INF/  and give the uri as **/WEB-INF/***xsdname***.xsd** in the XML file in which you are using the schema.